# How do I calculate the angle between the hour and minutes hands?

Tags: python, math, clock

I'm trying to workout this problem, but I am still struggling to understand the logic to solve this problem.

```
hour degree = 360 / 12 = 30
minutes degree = 360 / 12 / 60 = 0.5
```

So, according to this, I thought I could formulate the following function in python:

```
def clockangles(hour, min):
    return (hour * 30) + (min * 0.5)
```

For the hour, it works fine, as it appears to have a 1=1 mapping. But for the minute there is one problem at least. When it's 0 minutes, the minutes hand points to 12.

For example:

7pm: hands pointing to 7pm and minutes  pointing to 12

How do I calculate the minutes properly? Please help me understand the formula.

**EDIT:** For example, if I call the function above with 7pm, e.g clockangles(7,0) I get the value 210. However, according [this link](http://www.mathsisfun.com/activity/clocks-angles.html) the angle at 7:00 is 150

Comment: you should multiply `min` by .5, not divide it. (also, rename it to something else, that shadows the builtin)

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the angle between the hours and minutes hand? In which direction, because there are always two answers? Clockwise, anti-clockwise, the angle that is less than 180degrees?

Comment: Thanks roippi. Perhaps you could answer this one with more detail? :)

Comment: Also where is "0 degrees" at the twleve hand?

Comment: I've made the suggested corrections. I'ts a bit late and I'm sleepy. Thanks. Regarding the question from Lego Stormtroopr, I'm not sure. I presume it's the clockwise angle, but it's not very clear

Comment: So what is the expected output?  Do you need separate angles for the hour and minute hand?  Or...?

Comment: I've edited my question again roippi :)

Comment: Okay well 210 degrees (measuring clockwise) is the same as 150 degrees (measuring counterclockwise).  The linked page just uses the smaller of the two angles.  Also, are you finding the angle *between* the two hands?  The rest of your question does not seem to ask that, but your link does.

Comment: Yes,  I am trying to find the angle between the 2 hands. I will edit my question once again to clarify that.

Comment: 30*H-5.5*M=210-0=210

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay.  You are trying to find the angle between the two hands.  Then this:

```
minutes degree = 360 / 12 / 60 = 0.5
```

Is just the number of degrees the *hour* hand moves per minute.  Think about it - the minute hand travels a full 360 each hour.  Therefore there are only 60 minutes in a full revolution.  360/60 = 6 degrees per minute for the minute hand.

So, you need to find the difference between the hour and the minute hand. Thus the function now looks like:

```
def clockangles(hour, minute):
    return (hour * 30 + minute * 0.5) - (minute * 6)
```

Now, this is valid, so we could stop here.  However I should explain that this can give both answers larger than 180 degrees and negative angles.  If you don't want those things (and from your comments it appears that you don't), correct for them.

```
def clockangles(hour, minute):
    return abs((hour * 30 + minute * 0.5) - (minute * 6))
```

Now, no negative angles.

```
def clockangles(hour, minute):
    ans = abs((hour * 30 + minute * 0.5) - (minute * 6))
    return min(360-ans,ans)
```

Now, the shorter of the two angles formed by measuring clockwise and counterclockwise.

Comment: Thank you, could you just explain the "minute * 6" a bit more clearly? Also, in some cases, the hour point is not at an exact hour-angle, that is a part I haven't understood very well :)

Comment: @CaseyJones the hour hand moves as the minute hand moves, right? So if you're at 26 minutes, the hour hand will be 26/60ths between two hour numbers, right? [Here's an example of what the hour hand is doing.](http://www.mathsisfun.com/time-clocks-analog-digital.html)

Answer (score 2):

In the following solution, the variable *m* refers to minutes, and the variable *h* to hours.

Let's separate the problem into its components.

1. Find the angle of the minute hand from 12 o'clock.
2. Find the angle of the hour hand from 12 o'clock.
3. Find the absolute value of their difference.

Now, let's start solving each component.

1. The minute hand makes a full cycle every hour, or 60 minutes. Therefore, we can get the completed percentage of the cycle of the minute hand by `(m / 60)`. Since there are 360 degrees, we can get the angle of the minute hand from 12 o'clock by `(m / 60) * 360`.
2. The hour hand makes a full cycle every 12 hours. Since there are 24 hours in a day, we need to normalize the hour value to 12 hours. This is accomplished by `(h % 12)`, which returns the remainder of the hour value divided by 12.

   Now, as the minute hand makes its cycle, the hour hand does not just remain at the exact value of `(h % 12)`. In fact, it moves 30 degrees between `(h % 12)` and `(h % 12) + 1`. The amount by which the hour hand deviates from `(h % 12)` can be calculated by adding to `(h % 12)` the completed percentage of the cycle of the minute hand, which is `(m / 60)`. Overall, this gives us `(h % 12) + (m / 60)`.

   Now that we have the exact position of the hour hand, we need to get the completed percentage of the cycle of the hour hand, which we can get by `((h % 12) + (m / 60)) / 12`. Since there are 360 degrees, we can get the angle of the hour hand from 12 o'clock by `(((h % 12) + (m / 60)) / 12) * 360`.
3. Now that we have both the angle of the minute and hour hand from 12 o'clock, we simply need to find the difference between the two values, and take the absolute value (since the difference can be negative).

   So overall, we have `abs(((((h % 12) + (m / 60)) / 12) - (m / 60)) * 360)`.

Below is a python function that calculates this value. It will return whichever value of the angle that is the shortest.

```py
def find_angle(h, m):
    if abs(((((m/60)+(h%12))/12)-(m/60))*360) > 180:
        return 360 - abs(((((h % 12) + (m / 60)) / 12) - (m / 60)) * 360)
    return abs(((((h % 12) + (m / 60)) / 12) - (m / 60)) * 360)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider each hand in isolation first. The minutes hand of the clock rotates 360 degrees in 60 minutes so each minute represents 6 degrees. The hours hand of the clock rotates 360 degrees in 12 hours so we know it moves a total of 30 degrees after each hour, but you need to factor in the advancement of the hours hand between hours. i.e. at 3:30 the minutes hand is on 6 and the hours hand has progressed past 3. We can calculate this advancement simply by (minutes/60) * 30 degrees which is equivalent to minutes/2. So once we know the degrees of each hand we simply find the difference. And formula will be like

```
 degrees = Math.Abs(((hour*30.0 + minute/2.0) - minute*6.0) % 360)
```

Comment: fails on 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 1):

Use  the algorithm:

**1.Minute angle** = 360 * minutes / 60

**2.Hour angle** = [ 360 * (hour % 12) / 12 ] + [ 360 * (minutes / 60) * (1 / 12) ]

**3.Angle between hour and minute** = (hour angle - minute angle) % 360

> this *reduces* to **30 * hours - 5.5 * minutes**.

Answer (score 1):

1. Multiply hours by 60 that is convert it into minutes. 
                     hours*60=minutes
2. Now add the given minutes and converted minutes.

   given minutes + converted mintes = total minutes
3. Now divide the total minutes by 2,  that is to find its average. 
                     total minutes / 2
4. Now multiply given minutes by 6. 
                    given minutes * 6
5. Now subtract point 3 from point 4.

By this method you will get the accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on this problem and created an equation:

```
(hr*30)+(min/2)-(min*6)
```

or

```
(min*6)-(hr*30)-(min/2)
```

Comment: Why is this answer negative?

Answer (score 0):

```
h = int(input())
m = int(input())
angle = float(abs(11 /2 * m - 30 * h))
print(" {}:{} makes the following angle {}°".format(h, m, angle))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note :**
60min = 360deg
1min = 6deg

**eg:-**
consider time as ***2:20*** (ie. 2hr 20min)
abs((2hr*5) min - (20)min) = 10min

angle_1 = 10min x 6deg = 60deg 
angle_2 = 360deg - 60deg = 300deg (means the angle on the other side)

So out of the two angles angle_1 is small.
hence, **min_angle = 60deg**

```
def min_angle_bet_hr_min(hr, min):

    angle_1 = (hr*5 - min)*6
    angle_2 = 360 - angle_1

    if angle_1 < angle_2:
        min_angle = angle_1
    elif angle_1 > angle_2:
        min_angle = angle_2
    else:
        min_angle = 0

    return abs(min_angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

returns minimum non negative angle, supports 24 time format:

```
def clockangles(hour, minute):
    return -abs(abs((hour%12)*30 - minute*6)-180)+180
```

Answer (score 0):

This version of the accepted answer simplifies the formula in the second line. It returns the same result for all values of hour and minute.

```
def get_angles(hour, minute):
    ans = abs(11 * minute - 60 * hour) / 2
    return min(360 - ans, ans)
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: To extend on @YasharAhmadov's point, there are **ten existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **twenty votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful, but it's _especially_ important when the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community.

Answer (score -1):

```
  def clock_angle(time):
    constH = 360 / 12
    constM = 360 / 60
    if ":" in time:
        clock = time.split(":")
        c1 = int(clock[0])
        c2 = int(clock[1])
        if c1 >= 12:
            c1 -= 12
        rc1 = c1*constH + constH*(c2/60)
        rc2 = c2*constM
        if rc1 > rc2:
            result = (rc1-rc2)
            angle2 = 360-rc1+rc2
        else:
            result = (rc2-rc1)
            angle2 = 360-rc2+rc1
        if angle2 < result:
            result = angle2
        return result
    return 0
```

Comment: Please explain how your code fixes the problem specified in the question instead of providing code-only answers.