# Take integer Input with space and store the value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I am trying to solve the clock angle problem and there I had to take input like below:

Input

```
2
5 30
6 00
```

where The first line contains the number of test cases
T
.
Each test case contains two integers h and m representing the time in an hour and minute format.

I am trying to take input like this

```
size=int(input())

for i in range(size):
    h,m=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
```

but I'm unable to store the value for clock angle calculation as it's replacing the previous value.

Comment: is this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601427/how-do-i-calculate-the-angle-between-the-hour-and-minutes-hands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
size = int(input())
angle = []
clock = []

for i in range(size):
    Inp = input().split(' ')
    clock.append(Inp) # store input clock
    hour, minute = int(Inp[0]), int(Inp[1])
    ans = abs((hour * 30 + minute * 0.5) - (minute * 6))
    angle.append(min(360 - ans, ans)) # store angle

print(clock)
print(angle)
```

Output hour = 2, minute = 2  and hour = 12, minute = 2:

```
[[2, 2], [12, 2]]
[49.0, 11.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a list to contain the inputs outside the loop and append to it in each iteration:

```py
size=int(input())

clocks = []
for i in range(size):
    clocks.append(list(map(int,input().split(' '))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You practically answered the question yourself: don't overwrite the first input with the second until you're done with it.

```
size=int(input())

for i in range(size):
    h,m=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
    # Do you calculation here.
    hour_pos = h + m/60
    angle = ...
    print(angle)
```